React-native-paper InputText black background error
I have this error only on Android, has anyone been able to solve it? 
This is my component
export const InputText = ({isPassword=false, showPasswordIcon='eye', hidePasswordIcon='eye-off', ...rest}:Props) => {
const [ps, setPs] = useState(true);
const outlineStyle = {borderRadius: 15, borderWidth:2, backgroundColor: '#FFF', borderColor: colores.primary}

if(isPassword){
    return (<TextInput mode='outlined' contentStyle={{}} activeOutlineColor=''  secureTextEntry={ps} dense={true} label='dwdw' outlineStyle={outlineStyle} right={<TextInput.Icon icon={ps === true ? showPasswordIcon : hidePasswordIcon} onPress={() => setPs(!ps)} />} {...rest}/>)
}else{
    return (<TextInput mode='outlined'  dense={true} label='dwdw' outlineStyle={outlineStyle} {...rest}/>)
}

"react-native":"0.74.1"
"react-native-pager-view": "^6.2.0",
"react-native-paper": "^5.7.2"
